# meteorite mrt not working on ubuntu 14.01

Tags: node.js, npm, meteorite

```
jayesh@jayesh-VirtualBox:~/meteroapp/leadengine$ sudo npm install -g meteorite
[sudo] password for jayesh: 
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/meteorite
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/meteorite
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ddp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/1.3.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/wrench/1.3.9
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/prompt/0.2.11
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/colors/0.6.0-1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async/0.2.9
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rolling_timeout_exec
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/1.3.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ddp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/colors/0.6.0-1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/prompt/0.2.11
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async/0.2.9
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rolling_timeout_exec
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/wrench/1.3.9
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/meteor-ejson
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-srp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/faye-websocket
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pkginfo
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/read
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/revalidator
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/utile
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/winston
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/faye-websocket
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/read
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/meteor-ejson
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pkginfo
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/revalidator
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-srp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/utile
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/websocket-driver
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist/0.0.8
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/websocket-driver
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/winston
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/websocket-extensions
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist/0.0.8
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mute-stream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/deep-equal
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/i
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ncp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cycle
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/eyes
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/stack-trace
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inflight
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/once
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/websocket-extensions
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ncp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mute-stream
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/i
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/deep-equal
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/inflight
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cycle
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/eyes
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/once
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/stack-trace
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/wrappy
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/brace-expansion
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/wrappy
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/brace-expansion
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/balanced-match
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/concat-map/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/balanced-match
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/concat-map/0.0.1
/usr/local/bin/mrt -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/bin/mrt.js

> meteorite@0.9.3 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite
> sh ./completions/postinstall.sh

meteorite@0.9.3 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite
├── rolling_timeout_exec@0.0.1
├── colors@0.6.0-1
├── wrench@1.3.9
├── async@0.2.9
├── underscore@1.3.3
├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.2, minimist@0.0.10)
├── ddp@0.4.6 (node-srp@0.0.1, meteor-ejson@0.6.3, faye-websocket@0.7.3)
├── fstream@1.0.4 (inherits@2.0.1, graceful-fs@3.0.6, mkdirp@0.5.0, rimraf@2.3.2)
└── prompt@0.2.11 (revalidator@0.1.8, pkginfo@0.3.0, read@1.0.5, winston@0.6.2, utile@0.2.1)


jayesh@jayesh-VirtualBox:~/meteroapp/leadengine$ mrt
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

older version of nodejs runs with node command now its run by nodejs so we can resolve this by creating symlink to simply forward all the commands received as node to nodejs.

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```